# How to enable TernJS in sublime text with ES6 modules (Import Statements) on macOS

Tags: sublimetext3, es6-modules, tern, ternjs

It is really unclear how to setup `tern` to work with `Sublime Text` and `ES6 Modules`.

What steps should I need to take to enable it?

Answer (score 3):

1. Install `tern_for_sublime` using Sublime's `Package Control`
2. Also, install `Fix Mac Path` using Sublime's `Package Control` ([why?](https://github.com/int3h/SublimeFixMacPath))
3. Create a file named `.tern-config` in you **Home** directory (not your project):

   `/Users/<your-username>/.tern-config`

   ```
   {
     "plugins": {
       "node": {},
       "es_modules": {}
     },
     "libs": [
       "ecma5",
       "ecma6"
     ],
     "ecmaVersion": 6
   }
   ```
4. To automatically show completions after "." is typed, open your sublime preferences (found in Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings - User) and add this line:

   ```
   "auto_complete_triggers": [{ "characters": ".", "selector": "source.js"}]
   ```
5. *Optionally*, you can override settings per project by creating a `.tern-project` file in the *root* of your project.

   [image]

Enjoy.

Comment: Great! By the way, I want to know what your font face, it's beautiful!

Comment: Thank @YangMingYuan! (: I use Hack
https://github.com/chrissimpkins/Hack